# Match / not between quotes, with escapable quotes & multi-line

Tags: c++, regex

So I am trying to split / in C++, but that doesn't matter.

I have this regex pattern:

``` \/(?=(?:(?:\\.|[^"'``\\])*["'``](?:\\.|[^"'``\\])*['"``])*(?:\\.|[^"'``\\])*$) ```

It matches `/` which is not between ', ", ` and you can escape quotes.

Sadly, I don't know how to make it multi-line. I tried changing `.` to `[^]` and removing `$`, but that didn't work.

**This is what I am trying to achieve:**

`Inline code` - Match

> `/` something '/' . . . ' \' / \' ' . . . ' ' `/` ' '
>   ' 
>   / 
>   ' `/` "/"

Comment: Is it C++ or JavaScript?

Comment: Please add a code snippet to repro the issue.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen it is C++, but I just need JavaScript regex, that's all I need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There is no C++ snippet so...

Comment: regular expressions are not coming from java script. If you need a regular expression this has nothing to do with javascript. Otherwise it is unclear why you tagged javascript

Comment: ...btw it is unclear why you tagged C++ as well ;)

Comment: In C++, you may use various regex libraries, `Boost`, `std::regex`, `PCRE`, `PCRE2`. You may use various flavors with `std::regex`. JavaScript uses its own implementation of ECMA standard, and the latest one supports lookbehinds and Unicode category classes, something that `std::regex` ECMAScript flavor does not support.

Comment: Here, removed JavaScript tag.

Comment: This still has no real relevance to C++, the easiest way to give it some is to include a [mcve].

Comment: You may match all the substrings in your sample text with `(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*"|\`[^\`]*\`|[^/])+`, see https://regex101.com/r/Qefbbk/2. In C++, you may easily get both matched and non-matched texts.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Escape sequence doesn't work

Comment: [That is the least trouble, really](https://regex101.com/r/Qefbbk/3).

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew. You should post this as post not comment and i'd definetly put this as an answer.

Comment: I posted the corrected version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match the strings you want with

```
(?:'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^'\\]*)*'|"[^\\"]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*"|`[^\\`]*(?:\\[\s\S][^`\\]*)*`|[^/])+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qefbbk/4)

**Details**

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group matching ...

  - `'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^'\\]*)*'` - a single-quoted string literal (with escape sequence support)
  - `|` - or
  - `"[^"]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*"` - a double-quoted string literal (with escape sequence support)
  - `|` - or
  - `` `[^\\`]*(?:\\[\s\S][^`\\]*)*` `` - a backtick-quoted string literal (with escape sequence support)
  - `|` - or
  - `[^/]` - a char other than `/`
- `)+` -... one or more times.